# Hearing Clipping after using NAudio MixingSampleProvider

Tags: naudio

I'm hoping someone can help me.  I am using NAudio and am recording from multiple wsapiloopbackcapture devices and mixing them together.  None of this can be written to disk, so I am doing it all in memory and am ultimately loading the data into a concurrent dictionary for another process to use that I will develop later.  All this works except that whenever I run my thread to load my chunk data into my dictionary, when I play the audio back I hear a single clip sound and it coincides with how often I run the thread.  If I set it to run every 20 seconds then I hear a clip sound at the 20 second mark when I listen to the audio.  I need to get rid of this clipping and I can't figure out what is causing it.

Here are the basic steps

```
    private static WasapiLoopbackCapture Wavein = null;
    private static WasapiLoopbackCapture Wavein2 = null;
    private static WaveFormat pcm8k16bitSt = new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 2);
    private static WaveFormat pcm8k16bitMo = new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1);
    private static WaveFormat Bit16;
    private static byte[] DataHeader = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("data");
    private static List<byte> SBL = new List<byte>();
    private static List<byte> SBL2 = new List<byte>();
    private static byte[] chunkdata;
    private static byte[] chunkdata2;

internal static ConcurrentDictionary<DateTime, DataFrame> AllSpeakerBytes = new ConcurrentDictionary<DateTime, DataFrame>();

    int SdeviceNumber = 0;
    int SdeviceNumber2 = 0;
    private static MMDevice deviceToRecord = null;
    private static MMDevice deviceToRecord2 = null;

deviceToRecord = (new MMDeviceEnumerator().EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.All, DeviceState.Active))[SdeviceNumber];

deviceToRecord2 = (new MMDeviceEnumerator().EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.All, DeviceState.Active))[SdeviceNumber2];

RecordAllSpeakers();

        private void RecordAllSpeakers()
        {
            if (deviceToRecord != null)
            {
                Wavein = new WasapiLoopbackCapture(deviceToRecord);
                var silence = new SilenceProvider(Wavein.WaveFormat).ToSampleProvider();
                var wo = new WaveOutEvent();
                wo.DeviceNumber = SdeviceNumber;
                wo.Init(silence);
                wo.Play();
                Wavein.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs>(SsourceStream_DataAvailable);
                Wavein.StartRecording();
                SRecFlag = true;
            }
            if (deviceToRecord2 != null)
            {
                Wavein2 = new WasapiLoopbackCapture(deviceToRecord2);
                var silence = new SilenceProvider(Wavein2.WaveFormat).ToSampleProvider();
                var wo = new WaveOutEvent();
                wo.DeviceNumber = SdeviceNumber2;
                wo.Init(silence);
                wo.Play();
                Wavein2.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs>(SsourceStream2_DataAvailable);
                Wavein2.StartRecording();
                SRecFlag2 = true;
            }
}


        private void SsourceStream_DataAvailable(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!SRecFlag) return;
            if (Wavein.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample == 32)
            {
                #region NewStraightConvert
                using (RawSourceWaveStream RS = new RawSourceWaveStream(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded, WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(Wavein.WaveFormat.SampleRate, Wavein.WaveFormat.Channels)))
                using (Wave32To16Stream wav16 = new Wave32To16Stream(RS))
                using (MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    WaveFileWriter.WriteWavFileToStream(ms2, wav16);
                    ms2.Position = 0;
                    using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(ms2))
                    using (var conversionStream0 = new WaveFormatConversionStream(pcm8k16bitSt, reader))
                    using (var conversionStream1 = new WaveFormatConversionStream(pcm8k16bitMo, conversionStream0))
                    //using (var conversionStream2 = new WaveFormatConversionStream(muLaw8k8bit, conversionStream1))
                    {
                        byte[] SendingBytes;
                        using (MemoryStream ms3 = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            using (RawSourceWaveStream cc = new RawSourceWaveStream(conversionStream1, pcm8k16bitMo))
                            {
                                cc.Position = 0;
                                cc.CopyTo(ms3);
                                SendingBytes = ms3.ToArray();
                            }
                        }
                        if (SendingBytes.Length > 0)
                        {
                            //SslTcpClient.VociDataToSendST2.AddRange(SendingBytes);
                            SBL.AddRange(SendingBytes);
                        }
                    }
                }
                #endregion
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                byte[] outtovoci;
                Bit16 = new WaveFormat(Wavein.WaveFormat.SampleRate, 16, Wavein.WaveFormat.Channels);
                outtovoci = new byte[e.BytesRecorded];
                Array.Copy(e.Buffer, 0, outtovoci, 0, e.BytesRecorded);

                using (MemoryStream TESTWaveMS = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (MemoryStream TESTWaveMS2 = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (WaveFileWriter TESTwaveWriter = new WaveFileWriter(TESTWaveMS, Bit16))
                        {
                            TESTwaveWriter.Write(outtovoci, 0, outtovoci.Length);

                            TESTwaveWriter.Flush();
                            byte[] tbytes = TESTWaveMS.ToArray();

                            using (MemoryStream tstream = new MemoryStream(tbytes))
                            {
                                using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(tstream))

                                using (var conversionStream0 = new WaveFormatConversionStream(pcm8k16bitSt, reader))
                                using (var conversionStream1 = new WaveFormatConversionStream(pcm8k16bitMo, conversionStream0))
                                //using (var conversionStream2 = new WaveFormatConversionStream(muLaw8k8bit, conversionStream1))
                                {
                                    WaveFileWriter.WriteWavFileToStream(TESTWaveMS2, conversionStream1);
                                    byte[] tbytes2 = TESTWaveMS2.ToArray();
                                    int fPos = SearchBytes(tbytes2, DataHeader);
                                    if (fPos > 0)
                                    {
                                        fPos = fPos + 8;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        fPos = 0;
                                    }

                                    long SendingBytes = tbytes2.Length - fPos;
                                    byte[] WBack = new byte[SendingBytes];


                                    if (SendingBytes > 0)
                                    {
                                        Array.Copy(tbytes2, fPos, WBack, 0, SendingBytes);
                                        //SslTcpClient.VociDataToSendST2.AddRange(WBack);
                                        SBL.AddRange(WBack);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

}

        private void SsourceStream2_DataAvailable(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!SRecFlag2) return;
            if (Wavein2.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample == 32)
            {
                #region NewStraightConvert
                using (RawSourceWaveStream RS = new RawSourceWaveStream(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded, WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(Wavein2.WaveFormat.SampleRate, Wavein2.WaveFormat.Channels)))
                using (Wave32To16Stream wav16 = new Wave32To16Stream(RS))
                using (MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    WaveFileWriter.WriteWavFileToStream(ms2, wav16);
                    ms2.Position = 0;
                    using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(ms2))
                    using (var conversionStream0 = new WaveFormatConversionStream(pcm8k16bitSt, reader))
                    using (var conversionStream1 = new WaveFormatConversionStream(pcm8k16bitMo, conversionStream0))
                    //using (var conversionStream2 = new WaveFormatConversionStream(muLaw8k8bit, conversionStream1))
                    {
                        byte[] SendingBytes;
                        using (MemoryStream ms3 = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            using (RawSourceWaveStream cc = new RawSourceWaveStream(conversionStream1, pcm8k16bitMo))
                            {
                                cc.Position = 0;
                                cc.CopyTo(ms3);
                                SendingBytes = ms3.ToArray();
                            }
                        }
                        if (SendingBytes.Length > 0)
                        {
                            //SslTcpClient.VociDataToSendST2.AddRange(SendingBytes);
                            SBL2.AddRange(SendingBytes);
                        }
                    }
                }
                #endregion
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                byte[] outtovoci;
                Bit16 = new WaveFormat(Wavein2.WaveFormat.SampleRate, 16, Wavein2.WaveFormat.Channels);
                outtovoci = new byte[e.BytesRecorded];
                Array.Copy(e.Buffer, 0, outtovoci, 0, e.BytesRecorded);

                using (MemoryStream TESTWaveMS = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (MemoryStream TESTWaveMS2 = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (WaveFileWriter TESTwaveWriter = new WaveFileWriter(TESTWaveMS, Bit16))
                        {
                            TESTwaveWriter.Write(outtovoci, 0, outtovoci.Length);

                            TESTwaveWriter.Flush();
                            byte[] tbytes = TESTWaveMS.ToArray();

                            using (MemoryStream tstream = new MemoryStream(tbytes))
                            {
                                using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(tstream))

                                using (var conversionStream0 = new WaveFormatConversionStream(pcm8k16bitSt, reader))
                                using (var conversionStream1 = new WaveFormatConversionStream(pcm8k16bitMo, conversionStream0))
                                //using (var conversionStream2 = new WaveFormatConversionStream(muLaw8k8bit, conversionStream1))
                                {
                                    WaveFileWriter.WriteWavFileToStream(TESTWaveMS2, conversionStream1);
                                    byte[] tbytes2 = TESTWaveMS2.ToArray();
                                    int fPos = SearchBytes(tbytes2, DataHeader);
                                    if (fPos > 0)
                                    {
                                        fPos = fPos + 8;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        fPos = 0;
                                    }

                                    long SendingBytes = tbytes2.Length - fPos;
                                    byte[] WBack = new byte[SendingBytes];


                                    if (SendingBytes > 0)
                                    {
                                        Array.Copy(tbytes2, fPos, WBack, 0, SendingBytes);
                                        //SslTcpClient.VociDataToSendST2.AddRange(WBack);
                                        SBL2.AddRange(WBack);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

     }


        private async void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer3.Enabled = false;
            if (SRecFlag == true || SRecFlag2 == true)
            {
                await Task.Run(() => SyncSpeakers());
            }
            timer3.Interval = 20000;
            timer3.Enabled = true;
        }


        private static void SyncSpeakers()
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();
            WaveFileReader reader = null;
            WaveFileReader reader2 = null;
            MixingSampleProvider mixer = null;

            int lbc = SBL.Count();
            int lbc2 = SBL2.Count();
            int lowest = 0;

            int[] array = new int[] { lbc, lbc2 };

            lowest = array.Where(f => f > 0).Min();

            if (deviceToRecord != null && SBL.Count > 0)
            {
                chunkdata = new byte[lowest];
                Array.Copy(SBL.ToArray(), 0, chunkdata, 0, chunkdata.Length);
                SwaveWriterS1 = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter(ms, pcm8k16bitMo);
                SwaveWriterS1.Write(chunkdata, 0, chunkdata.Length);
                SwaveWriterS1.Flush();
                SBL.RemoveRange(0, lowest);
            }
            if (deviceToRecord2 != null && SBL2.Count > 0)
            {
                chunkdata2 = new byte[lowest];
                Array.Copy(SBL2.ToArray(), 0, chunkdata2, 0, chunkdata2.Length);
                SwaveWriterS2 = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter(ms2, pcm8k16bitMo);
                SwaveWriterS2.Write(chunkdata2, 0, chunkdata2.Length);
                SwaveWriterS2.Flush();
                SBL2.RemoveRange(0, lowest);
            }

            int SWaves = 0;

            if (Wavein != null && SRecFlag == true)
            {
                ms.Position = 0;
                reader = new WaveFileReader(ms);
                SWaves++;
            }
            if (Wavein2 != null && SRecFlag2 == true)
            {
                ms2.Position = 0;
                reader2 = new WaveFileReader(ms2);
                SWaves++;
            }

            if (SWaves == 1)
            {
                mixer = new MixingSampleProvider(new[] { reader.ToSampleProvider() });
            }
            else if (SWaves == 2)
            {
                mixer = new MixingSampleProvider(new[] { reader.ToSampleProvider(), reader2.ToSampleProvider() });
            }

            if (SWaves > 0)
            {
                using (MemoryStream lms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    WaveFileWriter.WriteWavFileToStream(lms, mixer.ToWaveProvider16());

                    byte[] SendingBytes;
                    using (MemoryStream ms35 = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (RawSourceWaveStream cc = new RawSourceWaveStream(lms, pcm8k16bitMo))
                        {
                            cc.Position = 0;
                            cc.CopyTo(ms35);
                            SendingBytes = ms35.ToArray();

                            SwaveWriter.Write(SendingBytes, 0, SendingBytes.Length);
                            SwaveWriter.Flush();

                            byte[] lByte = Compress(SendingBytes);

                            DataFrame aFrame2 = new DataFrame();
                            aFrame2.bytes = new byte[lByte.Length];
                            aFrame2.bytesRecorded = SendingBytes.Length;
                            lByte.CopyTo(aFrame2.bytes, 0);
                            AllSpeakerBytes.TryAdd(DateTime.UtcNow, aFrame2);
                            lByte = null;
                        }
                    }


                }
            }
         }

        internal static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
        {
            try
            {
                //return data;
                using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (DeflateStream dstream = new DeflateStream(output, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
                    {
                        dstream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    }
                    return output.ToArray();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ERR5)
            {
                //Logging.LogData($"Failure in Compress: {ERR5.ToString()}");
                return null;
            }
        }


        internal static byte[] Decompress(byte[] data)
        {
            //return data;
            try
            {
                using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(data))
                    {
                        using (DeflateStream dstream = new DeflateStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                        {
                            dstream.CopyTo(output);
                        }
                    }
                    return output.ToArray();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ERR5)
            {
                //Logging.LogData($"Failure in Decompress: {ERR5.ToString()}");
                return null;
            }
        }


    class DataFrame
    {
        public byte[] bytes { get; set; }
        public int bytesRecorded { get; set; }
        public string extraData { get; set; } = "";
    }


        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Wavein != null)
            {
                Wavein.StopRecording();
                Wavein.Dispose();
                Wavein = null;
            }
            if (Wavein2 != null)
            {
                Wavein2.StopRecording();
                Wavein2.Dispose();
                Wavein2 = null;
            }
            mp3WriterAllSpk = new NAudio.Lame.LameMP3FileWriter(FinalSRFilename, pcm8k16bitMo, 64);
            List<DateTime> SpkWrites = AllSpeakerBytes.Select(k => k.Key).OrderBy(c => c).ToList();
            foreach (DateTime DT in SpkWrites)
            {
                byte[] outgoing = Decompress(AllSpeakerBytes[DT].bytes);
                mp3WriterAllSpk.Write(outgoing, 0, AllSpeakerBytes[DT].bytesRecorded);
            }

            mp3WriterAllSpk.Dispose();

            SRecFlag = false;
            SRecFlag2 = false;
}
```

This code needs a lot of cleaning up but basically the SyncSpeakers() is being ran every 20 seconds and I am hearing a clipping at 20 second increments of the audio.  If I change the timer to run every 10 seconds I will hear a clip sound every 10 seconds of the resulting audio.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by shaving the first 100 bytes off of the front and replacing them with byte 101.  If there is a better way I'd love to hear it.

Thanks!